# Hive: how to convert yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:SS:sssZ into hour units

Tags: datetime, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have the following timestamps:

```
2020-03-09T07:34:06:825Z
2020-03-09T07:54:12:220Z
2020-03-09T03:54:11:041Z
2020-03-09T09:22:10:220Z
2020-03-09T11:13:36:217Z
2020-03-09T11:23:26:040Z
2020-03-09T11:43:35:721Z
```

And I would like to convert them in hourly unit such as:

```
2020-03-09T07:00:00
2020-03-09T07:00:00
2020-03-09T03:00:00
2020-03-09T09:00:00
2020-03-09T11:00:00
2020-03-09T11:00:00
2020-03-09T11:00:00
```

Will this be possible? Any help will be appreciate. Stackoverflow has been a life saver. It could be in datetime or string format.
Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **`unix_timestamp`** and **`from_unixtime`** functions to convert and format the timestamp required.

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(string("2020-03-09T07:34:06:825Z"),"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss:SSS'Z'"),"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:00:00") as new_ts;

+-------------------+
|new_ts             |
+-------------------+
|2020-03-09T07:00:00|
+-------------------+
```

---

**`Explanation:`**

```
unix_timestamp(
string("2020-03-09T07:34:06:825Z"), --sample data
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss:SSS'Z'") --match the data format
```

---

```
from_unixtime('unix_timestamp...etc',"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:00:00") --to format as required
```

Comment: could you help me with another format of time ? In the form of `03-18-2020 17:27:02:153` I tried to use `select concat_ws(':',from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(split('03-18-2020 17:27:02:153','\\.')[0],'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss')),split('03-18-2020 17:27:02:153','\\.')[1])` It is not giving me the milliseconds..

Answer (score 1):

Using regexp_replace:

```
with your_data as (
select stack(
'2020-03-09T07:34:06:825Z',
'2020-03-09T07:54:12:220Z',
'2020-03-09T03:54:11:041Z',
'2020-03-09T09:22:10:220Z',
'2020-03-09T11:13:36:217Z',
'2020-03-09T11:23:26:040Z',
'2020-03-09T11:43:35:721Z'
) as str
)

select regexp_replace(str,'(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})T(\\d{2}).*','$1T$2:00:00') 
   from your_data;
```

Result:

```
2020-03-09T07:00:00
2020-03-09T07:00:00
2020-03-09T03:00:00
2020-03-09T09:00:00
2020-03-09T11:00:00
2020-03-09T11:00:00
2020-03-09T11:00:00
```

Explanation:

Regular expression defines two groups:

$1 is date part `(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})`

$2 is hour part after T '(\d{2})' 
everything else at the end `.*` is ignored.

You extract `'$1T$2:00:00'`